Wrong constructor being called causes segmentation fault
I have two classes that are independently declared in their own header and have their methods defined in their own  TUs /.cpp's.
the classes are the same name-wise and namespace-wise, but exist in different directories in the code base, and have different functionalities, they look like the following:
core1/abc1.h:
namespace ns {
   class abc {
   ....
      std::map<std::string,int> m;  
   };
}


core1/abc1.cpp:
    namespace ns {
       abc:~abc() {
       
      };
    }


core2/abc2.h:
namespace ns {
   class abc {
   
      std::unordered_map<std::string,int> m;  
   };
}
  

core1/abc2.cpp:
namespace ns {
   abc:~abc() {
   
  };
}

When i run my program that uses both the classes, when the program ends and the destructors are being called it seems based on gdb for the instance that is of the type that comes from abc2.h, the destructor that is for abc1.h type is being called, which then causes a segfault.
I see the error when using g++ and clang, could this be an undefined behavior issue? or potentially a linker bug? (linker is gold)

when building the symbol name for use with the linker, is the filename taken into account - or it is only the namespace, class, method names the only factors taken into account?

"but exist in different directories in the code base" -- This has absolutely no impact on how it is compiled. If you read your question without this information about directories, do you see the problem?

What is the One-Definition Rule?

One definition rule warning is possibly a duplicate, although that question does not use namespaces and it does not mention file locations. The differences make no impact, so maybe this should be closed as a duplicate of that one? Or should there be an answer saying that the differences make no impact.

I'm more concerned about if this could be a linker issue where it's selecting the wrong destructor based on how the names are mangles, assuming the destructor name  ends up being the same for both, the linker ends up selecting the first one it has in it's internal map/store. - @JaMiT mind making your comments into an answer as they seem very relevant.

Since the classes have the same name in the same namespace, and they are different, its an ODR violation.  Just name the two different classes with two different names.

"the symbol name . . . is the filename taken into account" No. It is not part of the source code and is irrelevant. If it was, global variables wouldn't work as they would be a different variable in each translation unit.

Your abc1.h and abc2.h both define a class ns::abc  - the result (if they are used in the same project) is undefined behaviour. Similarly abc1.cpp and abc2.cpp both define a function ns::abc::~abc() - which, again, results in undefined behaviour.   One possible symptom (there are many possibilities) of undefined behaviour is a seg fault.   To fix the problem, eliminate both sources of undefined behaviour.  For example, remove one of the headers and corresponding sources from your project OR rename one of the classes (e.g. placing it in another namespace).

And, BTW, thank your lucky stars that you experienced the seg fault.  A more sinister possibility when behaviour is undefined is that your program SEEMS to work correctly (e.g. passes all tests).   But breaks for some reason after being delivered to an end user - because the end user uses the program in a manner you haven't tested for.   End users (who are often paying customers) often get irate about such things - particularly if you can't fix the problem.

What is going on here is fundamentally due to the decoration scheme (aka name mangling) which does not have its specification defined in the standard and instead is Implementation Defined, and how this name mangling scheme is being used is causing a One Definition Rule (ODR) violation.
Given a translation unit (TU), which is a pre-processed form of implementable source code typically .cpp files, there's a mechanism the compiler uses to name specific parts of the code so that each is uniquely identifiable within the TU.
such codes as class methods, free functions, and global variables etc.
For example lets assume the following TU from a file called file.cpp:
#include <...>
#include <...>

namespace stuff {

  bool foo(int v) {....}
  bool foo(double v) {....}

}

The name mangled versions of foo might look like the following (there's no common format, it's implementation defined):
stuff_bool_foo_int
stuff_bool_foo_double

These names are attached to the code as identifying "symbols" all the way from the compiler front-end, middle layer (IR), back-end (assembler linker)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling
The issue you are seeing would probably be similar to if the int version of the foo free function was defined in a similarly named namespace in another TU.
What happens next is implementation defined, but generally speaking the following occurs in the linking stage:

Linker grabs all the symbols and associated object code
One by one, it adds these pairs to a map like structure eg: code_map[smybol_id] = object_code
During linking when a reference to a symbol is encountered, it looks up the symbol to get the associated object_code
Linker injects the object code to that reference location, if symbol is not found in the map you will see an undefined symbol error diagnostic

The issue you're seeing is happening at step 2 - given the data structure is most likely a map and not a multi-map, the second time the symbol name/key is seen the implementation may either:

Override the original value
Ignore the second value

Either way, it's guaranteed that at least one or more call sites (reference points) will have the wrong object code injected, and this is why C++ has the One-Definition-Rule (ODR)
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition
There is no portable (across multiple compilers/linkers) way to resolve the issue other than renaming one or both of the classes such that they resolve to uniquely identifiable.
In short you're seeing Undefined Behaviour - which means anything goes.
The simplest solution is to rename one the classes or change the namespace of one of the classes.

It's not a bug, it's an UB, a result of wrongly organized project.
File names have no impact on linkage, only full-id. Standard states that barring items with local linkage, having two definition of a
variable, function, class type, enumeration type or template is undefined behavior.
Usually conflicts can be detected by linker but it is possible to avoid them due transformation made to original code, e.g. inlining or full-program optimization. At linkage level the structure of class is no longer preserved, only the function code and vtable, if any present.  If function calls were fully inlined, its name may be absent from symbol table included into generated object code file. Full program optimzation literally can do whatever, assuming that there is only one destructor.
In that case you both may never encounter a error, if each version of class had only inline memebers and an insstance of such never is used in another module and you may encounter very odd bugs, sometimes nature of which can be found only by looking into assembler code. No name conflict - no error from linker.
Running debugger may cause you either fail to link with debug information or show wrong code executed. Consider yourself lucky. Similar bugs with difference in vtable, one class had more virtual functions than another, I had to diagnose by comparing offsets used by calling code in assembler of unknown to me architecture.

This is a result of the One Definition Rule.  If at the linker stage, there are multiple implementations of the same function (weakly defined), then the linker is allowed to arbitrarily choose any one.
The fix is to make sure the different things have different names (extra namespaces for the distinguishing features.


when building the symbol for use with the linker, is the filename taken into account

No. This relates to a difficulty compilers have had implementing #pragma once (which is a non-standard preprocessor directive that indicates a file should be processed only once, similar to include guards). It is easy for a preprocessor to track which files have already been pulled in via #include directives. It takes a bit more effort, but still not difficult, to track those files using canonical paths (where, for example, a path like project/src/../include gets simplified to project/include). A difficulty comes when the operating system supports symbolic links.
A particular library can have multiple paths to it. For example, there might be a library installed in /usr/local/boost_1_82_0, where the name helps keep older versions of the library from interfering with newer versions. However, for convenience, there might be a symbolic link that makes /usr/local/include/boost an alias for /usr/local/boost_1_82_0/boost so that it is easier to use this library and so that upgrading the library can be largely painless (just update the symbolic link).
So it is possible to have two canonical paths that refer to the same file. For example /usr/local/boost_1_82_0/boost/bimap.hpp and /usr/local/include/boost/bimap.hpp might refer to the same file. Should the compiler treat these as different files because their paths are nominally different? No, they name the same file. (There might issues upgrading the library if a single project uses both paths, but that's a separate concern.) For people implementing #pragma once, this is a challenge. For the current question, it is a demonstration of why the preprocessor must not take the file's name into account.
The above shows reasoning from a user's perspective. There are also technical reasons why the path is not factored in. Perhaps most notably, processing #include occurs in an earlier phase of translation than analyzing semantics. This answer is geared towards those looking for a rationale rather than technicalities.

or it is only the namespace, class, method names the only factors taken into account?

This is ambiguously worded, which makes a hard "yes" or "no" tricky. What matters is the fully qualified name (the name including namespaces, such as ::std::vector or ::boost::bimaps::bimap). It is true that methods have fully qualified names, and in this respect method names are taken into account. However, I suspect the intent was to ask if the method names are taken into account when identifying a class, and in that context, they are not.
A class is identified by its fully qualified name. The fully qualified name of a class includes its identifier and namespace, but its methods are not part of this. If there are different definitions for the same fully qualified name, such as two definitions for ::ns::abc, then the One Definition Rule has been violated and your compiler is free to do anything.
What you have run into is a name conflict, of the sort that namespaces are intended to avoid. However, this solution does fail if the name conflict is of the namespace itself. (It appears that core1 and core2 unfortunately chose the same namespace to use.)
